# Select data using utf-8 character encoding from hive

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, beeline, spark-shell

I am selecting data from my hive table/view but the character encoding is not picked up by the spark-shell or beeline, but if I am selecting the same data from Ambari(Directly throguh Hive), but from command line Hive has been disabled for security reasons.
Please see the below data:

```
Ambari Data:

•Construction Maintenance 
• 524 N. Martin Luther King Jr.
‘SS-MN-BAE – Other’
¿NPM¿ GOVT/GS SCD US ARM
¿MCCRAY,LORENZO

beeline data:
?Construction Mai...
? 524 N. Martin L...
?SS-MN-BAE ? Other?
?NPM? GOVT/GS SCD...
?MCCRAY,LORENZO

Spark-shell Data:
?Construction Mai...
? 524 N. Martin L...
?SS-MN-BAE ? Other?
?NPM? GOVT/GS SCD...
?MCCRAY,LORENZO
```

```
using spark shell I did
 sql("select * from test.ACCOUNT order by customer_name desc").show()

Same select is issued in beeline and ambari.
```

if any one know what I am doing wrong or if I need to set any parameter to read the proper char set, please let me know I have tried java nio charset in spark shell but nothing worked out. Please guide me, pretty new to Hadoop. Is there a way I can pass the character set to beeline or spark-shell through command line before selecting the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read the data in the linux in the proper encoding, after logging into the linux, in my profile I have set the character type by using below variables:

```
export LANG="pt_PT.utf8"
```

```
export LC_ALL="pt_PT.utf8"
```

and reloaded the profile if it bash_profile then `. .bash_profile` if it is just profile then `. .profile`

Answer (score 1):

This is not a Hive issue rather a file system or file encoding issue. SELECT * in Hive actually does nothing except read the file from file system. So if you run a hadoop fs cat on your underlying file, you should see the same behavior.

Comment: is there a way to read the data properly in utf-8?, underlying file is also showing "?".

Comment: Check this link, may be helpful - https://www.tecmint.com/convert-files-to-utf-8-encoding-in-linux/

Comment: Thank you very much for the response @ASK I found the solution.

Comment: That's great... keep going